# Laravel refresh specific seeder

Tags: laravel

I added a few more lines into my `PermissionsTableSeeder` and now am looking to refresh that seeder while next deployment. My app in production so `migration:refresh --seed` is not an option.

I have tried the below, but it does nothing (thou I have success notice).

```
php artisan db:seed --class=PermissionsTableSeeder
```

Is there a way to wipe and seed a specific table?

Thanks

Comment: try running `composer dump-autoload`. If not work show us the code.

Comment: doesn't help for that case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually do this in my seeders:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class PermissionsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('permissions')->truncate();

        // your seed logic here
    }
}
```

so when I run:

```
php artisan db:seed --class=PermissionsTableSeeder
```

the `truncate()` method will remove all rows and reset the auto-incrementing ID to zero before the inserts.

Comment: This is it! Thanks!